# How can I make the temperature visible in indicator-weather in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, indicator

I've got Lubuntu 11.10 with `indicator-weather` installed, but `indicator-weather` doesn't show the current temperature.

[image: The temperature isn't shown in indicator-weather.]

Resizing the panel doesn't work, and the application isn't shown in the panel preferences. How can I make `indicator-weather` show the temperature?

[image: The menu doesn't show indicator-weather.]

Comment: This is a bug - you should subscribe to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/884579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

There is a report on Launchpad with a similar/if not the same issue.

I would suggest you subscribe to this [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/884579) to receive updates.

Launchpad Janitor has marked this as *affecting multiple users* - so you are not alone!